# Transaction in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I need to execute several sql clauses, inserts, updates and delete for example. How to use a transaction in Access to bind them together?

DAO is preferred.

like:

```
BeginTrans
Excute SQL_1
Excute SQL_2
.....
CommitTrans
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use DAO, you can use the `BeginTrans` and `CommitTrans` methods of the global `DBEngine` object:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

DBEngine.BeginTrans
db.Execute SQL_1
db.Execute SQL_2
...
DBEngine.CommitTrans
```

Comment: If there's something wrong in the transaction, where should I put the ROLLBACK? In error handler?

Answer (score 24):

Here is a more complete skeleton...

```
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim in_trans As Boolean

Sub Transaction()
On Error GoTo Trans_Error
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    in_trans=True
    ws.BeginTrans

    <do some SQL stuff; maybe use Err.Raise>

    ws.CommitTrans
    in_trans=False
Trans_Exit:
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Trans_Error:
    If in_trans = True Then
         ws.Rollback
    EndIf
    Resume Trans_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. This is actually much better than the example MS gives in their documentation.

Comment: I'd replace `Resume Trans_Exit` with `' Do the rest of your error handling here`, since logging the error, showing a message, rethrowing the error or returning some error code are usually more appropriate than just "silently" rolling back. In addition, since `ws` and `in_trans` are just needed inside of the Sub, I'd put their declarations inside the Sub as well.

Comment: I agree with @Heinzi.  At minimum I would add: `MsgBox Error$` to provide some feedback rather than simply rolling back.